# Python Scripts is not running after working C Project and VSCode IntelliSense is on Partial Partial Mode

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

So I was just done editing my C project in VS Code, and I went to work back on my Python project in VS Code, but now Python scripts is not working or running anymore or even showing anything on the output window on VS Code (as shown in the figure below). I keep pressing Run & Run Python File in Terminal but everything remains exactly the same with no output.

I could see that the **IntelliSense** is mentioning that it's on **Partial Mode** which it was not the case before working on the C project.

I reset my settings.json file to reset everything as it was before but an it doesn't work. Even uninstall and install VS Code again was not helpful and Python script is still not working.

**I have the "Python" extension installed (the one made by Microsoft).**

Any recommendation or advice would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Many extensions (including my own) require you to open a folder first so as to enable all necessary features. I don't think Microsoft's Python extension is any exception here.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Mode is relatively rare. According to the content you provide, I think it may be caused by the following reasons:
The project is currently loading. Once loading completes, you will start getting project-wide IntelliSense for it. In these cases, VS Code's IntelliSense will operate in partial mode. Partial mode tries its best to provide IntelliSense for any Python files you have open, but is limited and is not able to offer any cross-file IntelliSense features.
I think you could spend more time waiting for vscode to load. Of course, if it still doesn't work, you could reinstall the python extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MingJie for your feedback and suggestion .. Unfortunately, after trying several options, the problem was only solved by uninstalling VSCode completely and starting again from a new one.